# Add appsync as subgraph to apollo graphql supergraph

Tags: graphql, apollo, aws-appsync, apollo-federation, apollo-studio

I have apollo **supergraph** created with two **subgraphs** working perfectly. I have used Rover commands to join subgraphs with supergraph.

Now I'm trying to add **appsync** as a subgraph to my supergraph. I have changed in the appsync schema as required apollo. Using rover command i have joined appsync as subgraph. I'm able to see appsync schema and queries in apollo graphql studio.

But issue is when i tried to query the appsync schema I'm getting the error "**You are not authorized to make this call**". In appsync we get this error when don't pass **x-api-key** in the headers. I'm not able to find a way to send x-api-key to subgraph. I have tried by adding headers in while querying the super graph but no luck. I have tried adding the headers section in the **rover.yml** like this, but not successful.
headers:
all:
request:
- propagate:
named: "x-api-key"

Can you please help me.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. My appsync key got expired in 7 days. I have regenerated the key and tested, its working fine.